# Coldfusion cookie login

Tags: cookies, authentication, coldfusion

I'm new to using cookies to login with coldfusion.

I think I'm relativity close to figuring out how to login with cookies, but still unsure how to have every page refrence the login check properly.
I want every page in my site to be referenced to the login.

This is the login page:

```
<cfif IsDefined("cookie.username")>
    <!--- a cookie exist, so let's put in this username automatically into the form --->
    <cfset username = cookie.username>
<cfelse>
    <!--- a cookie DOES NOT exist, so let's put a blank value in the username field --->
    <cfset username = "">
</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined("cookie.password")>
   <!--- a cookie exist, so let's put in this password automatically into the form --->
    <cfset password = cookie.password>
<cfelse>
   <!--- a cookie DOES NOT exist, so let's put a blank value in the password field --->
   <cfset password = "">
</cfif>
<cfoutput>
<form action="LoginProcess.cfm" method="post">
   <table width="500" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="500" colspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="250">Username:</td>
        <td width="250"><input type="text" name="username" value="#username#"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="250">Password:</td>
        <td width="250"><input type="password" name="password" value="#password#"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="250">Remember Me</td>
        <td width="250"><input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" value="Yes"
                                   <cfif IsDefined("cookie.username") OR
                                   IsDefined("cookie.password")>CHECKED</cfif>></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="250"></td>
        <td width="250"><input type="submit" name="Process" value="Login"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
</cfoutput>
```

This is the page the processed the Login process and takes the user to the mainpage of the website.

```
<cfquery name="qVerify" datasource="SodaWebsite">
    SELECT        *
    FROM           Admins
    WHERE         Username = '#FORM.username#' AND Password = '#FORM.password#'
</cfquery>
<cfif qVerify.RecordCount>

   <!--- this user is good, before actually logging them in, see if their information will be saved for next time --->
     <cfif IsDefined("RememberMe")>
         <!--- members wants their information remembered, so set the cookies --->
          <cfcookie name="username" value="#form.username#" expires="NEVER">
          <cfcookie name="password" value="#form.password#" expires="NEVER">
    <cfelse>
          <!--- member does NOT want their information remember, EXPIRE their cookies NOW so they are deleted for good! --->
          <cfcookie name="username" value="#form.username#" expires="NOW">
          <cfcookie name="password" value="#form.password#" expires="NOW">
    </cfif>

    <!--- now that you're done with the cookie, follow the REGULAR login procedures as you regularly do --->
</cfif>


<cfif IsDefined(cookie.username) and IsDefined(cookie.password)>
<cfabort>
<Cfelse>
<cfinclude template="Index.cfm">
</cfif>
```

For the actual first page I'm only showing up to the header portion, since I believe it goes there.

```
<html>
<head>
<cfif isdefined(Cookie.Username) and isdefined(Cookie.password)>
<cfabort>
<cfelse>
<cfinclude template="LoginProcess.cfm">
</cfif>

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: The first thing you need to deal with is to revise how you store and access your login information: you appear to be storing your passwords in clear-text, and you are allowing site users to pass SQL to your DB by hard-coding their inputs in your SQL string, rather than passing them as parameters to the SQL statement. Get that fixed first before worrying about anything else.

Comment: You should also not be storing their passwords in clear text in a cookie!!!

Comment: hmm... aren't you always aborting before you even get to the login cfm, if the cookies exist?? or does your first snippet happen before that.

Comment: Otherwise this should theoretically work, even though it is not very secure/safe. You should place this code inside of the sessionStart method in your application.cfc, it should only need to be ran once. after that, you should set a session variable that you use throughout your application to see if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: I wasn't really "eluding your question", given I wasn't attempting to answer it. Your approach is fundamentally flawed, so there's rework to do before getting around to addressing the question. IE: having the user's pwd in a cookie is a nono, so it would not be part of the functionality you're undertaking. So that needs a rethink first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the login check to happen for every page request, place it in the onRequest method. However, it would make more sense to do the cookie check only once using the `onSessionStart` method, then use the `onRequest` to either send the user to the requested page, or to send them to the login page.

```
// this belongs in application.cfc, convert to tag-based if you prefer.
function onSessionStart() {
    session.userid = 0;
    if (cookies were valid) { // replace with your cookie check logic
        session.userid = theuserid;
    }
}

function onRequest(template) {
    if (session.userid == 0) {
        include template="/login.cfm";
    }
    else {
        include template=template;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the `session.userid` in `login.cfm` on successful login before you redirect.

---

You should really re-think your password storage and what you are using inside the cookie, storing the username/password in a cookie and storing the password as plain text in the database isn't secure. Your query is also wide-open to sql-injection attacks.

Remember, the purpose of making your login system secure is about more than your application, it's about keeping your users safe. If you don't protect your users, you could be putting them all at risk of losing personal information (in some cases, more than just what you store in your database.)